# Eclipse error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

Here is the exact error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Application.main(Application.java:22)
```

I've tried to fix it with what I know... what am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
public class Application {

private String guitarMaker; 

public void setMaker(String maker) {

    guitarMaker = maker;

}

public String getMaker() {

    return guitarMaker;

}

public static void main (String[] args) {

    Application[] guitarists;
    guitarists = new Application[1];

    guitarists[0].setMaker("Example maker");
    System.out.println("My guitar maker is " + guitarists[0].getMaker());

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new Application[1]` creates an array of one element, and all elements  in that array (in this case, "all the elements" is "that only element") are `null` by default. That means that `guitarist[0]` is null, and calling `setMaker` on it will result in the NullPointerException.

You need to instantiate a guitarist and set assign it to `guitarist[0]`:

```
guitarist[0] = new Application();
```

Comment: I see... I forgot to create an object for guitarist[0]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Application {

private String guitarMaker; 

public void setMaker(String maker) {

    guitarMaker = maker;

}

public String getMaker() {

    return guitarMaker;

}

public static void main (String[] args) {

    Application[] guitarists;
    guitarists = new Application[1];
    guitarists[0] = new Application(); //need to create a new object
    guitarists[0].setMaker("Example maker");
    System.out.println("My guitar maker is " + guitarists[0].getMaker());

}

}
```

You were calling a method on a null object. The `new Application[1]` just creates an array after that you need to make new objects in each index of the array

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialise array with size and call `new Application()` instead of `new Application[1]` something like:

```
Application[] guitarists = new Application[1];
guitarists[0] = new Application();

guitarists[0].setMaker("Example maker");
System.out.println("My guitar maker is " + guitarists[0].getMaker());
```